# How to add new options to my WordPress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-options

I'm the author of a small and simple WordPress plugin based on WodPress Plugin Boilerplate using [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate Generator](https://wppb.me/).
My plugins is [Language Switcher for Transposh](https://wordpress.org/plugins/language-switcher-for-transposh/): it just allows to get a nicer language switcher if you're using [Transposh Language Filter](https://transposh.org/) plugin (currently cut off by WordPress repo).

In the last version I have added a couple of options but I have realized that during the update the activation hook is not called so the new options aren't written to the database with the obvious consequence that my users get warning messages in the dashboard.

What is the correct way to manage this situation?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing a set of options, or a single option with a schema, you should do the following:

- keep a version number stored in the database, ideally as a separate value, though if you are using a single option with an array inside it, you could store it there
- keep a version number in your plugin as a defined value in a file
- on `init` or `admin_init`, compare the value in your plugin against the value in the database

  - if they differ, run an upgrade function

This way your plugins data gets updated, even if no update/activation/deactivation occurs. Your existing method would fail if an old backup was restored, or a plugin was manually updated via FTP. This is what plugins such as GravityForms do, and they take advantage of this system to implement multiple functions to upgrade from 2 -> 3 -> 4 etc

You can also use the PHP function `version_compare` to use version comparisons:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

```php
$version = ... get version from database;
if ( ! $version ) {
    // fresh install!
    do_first_time_install_of_marcos_plugin();
} else if ( version_compare( MARCOS_PLUGIN_VERSION, $version, '>') ) {
    // the plugin version is higher than what's in the DB!
    do_marcos_plugin_upgrade();
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for trying to help. But taht's not my problem. I already do what you suggest (just a bit different since I use an array for my options) and I do it in the activation hook. The problem is that WordPress doesn't call activation hook when plugins are updated. So I was wondering how to solve this problem. But I have finally found it (read my own answer, please).

Comment: hmm I think there's an important part to your question that you didn't mention and assumed was obvious, that you're not just adding options, you're updating options, or that you're changing options used by another plugin. I wrote my answer under the assumption you were adding new options only used in your plugin. Is that not the case? The activation hook should be unnecessary for options if the code is built correctly

Comment: Yes you're right, I've not been clear enough: I'm updating my plugins and I have added some new options (but no, I'm not updating options used by another plugin). Why you say that ·he activation hook should be unnecessary for options if the code is built correctly"? AFAIK, options are updated when the plugin is updated and WP doesn't deactivate and reactivate a plugin when it is updated so I thought I needed to call activation hook manually some way (as confirmed in the article I have cited. Do you think I'm wrong here?

Comment: that doesn't make sense, options are updated when you call `update_option` or when a registered setting is saved, it's clear that there is missing context and a mental model that is not shared here that is required to understand the question. Perhaps if you can talk in concrete terms rather than hiding things with abstract terms and generic concepts? Since `register_setting` is not a one time function call that happens when a plugin is activated, it's like post registration, it happens at runtime and needs to happen repeatedly, it is not persisted.

Comment: I suspect this problem is one that does not exist, and that you're mistakenly calling `register_setting` on plugin activation thinking that it registers a setting that then gets put in the database somewhere, and don't realise that it needs to be called one very page load, and has nothing to do with plugin activation. The way to change your registered setting is to just modify the parameters passed to that function, there is no database entry that needs changing, or columns in the option table. The data that `register_setting` registers only exists for the remainder of that specific request

Comment: More concrete? In the last version of the plugin I have added a new option, called Automode, which can be set to On or Off. This option dind't exist in the previous version of the plugin, so my record in the wp_options table had ro be changed: Automode had be added to the array of the options. But once I have updated the plugin in a testing website I have realized that the new options had not been added. In the article I have linked in my own answer everything is explained very clearly. I apologize if I have offended you, it was not my intention :) Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Ah, you did not mention that you actually have a single option that contains structured data that you're trying to change sub-parts of, that changes everything about your question

Comment: Not sure to understand (I'm not an expert): but if I were storing each option in a different record, the new option would still be written in the database, isn't it? How the fact that I use an array changes everything in my question? I'm missing something crucial here and perhaps you can help me to learn something really ineteresting about the way WordPress processes the plugins' options.

Comment: if you're using a data structure inside an option then only a single record exists in the database, and the data is serialised as a string, which means my answer no longer makes sense in this context. Option values are always plaintext strings in the database, any arrays or objects etc are flattened into strings on save by WordPress, so if you set an option with a value that's an array, the value in the database is the same as `serialize( $array )`, e.g. `[ 1,2,3,4]` becomes the string  `a:4:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;}` then gets deserialised by WP when retrieved

Comment: also, registration has nothing to do with your problem, so that's a red herring that will confuse people. You can rephrase your question as: _"I have an option that contains an array of several settings. When I activate my plugin I update a version value, but how do I do this on plugin update?"_, I know it might seem like I've just repeated what you've said, but other people will read that very differently

Comment: I've rewritten my answer

Comment: That's okay and now your answer actually solves my problem (as the article I have mentioned). The next time I'll be more careful describing the problem avoiding any types of unmotivated assumptions. Thank you so much for your effort and your patience. On to hte next

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found an answer in this very clear article at Sitepoint: [WordPress Plugin Updates the Right Way](https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-plugin-updates-right-way/). It is surprising I didn't get this result before, but evidently my search terms was not accurate enough.

The solution is to create a function to call when the plugin is loaded: in this function we have to check the current plugin version (which in WP Plugin Boilerplate is stored in a constant in the main plugin file) and the version number stored in the options (we must store and update the plugin version within your plugin's options). If the 2 versions are different we call our activation hook and *voilà, les jeux sont fait!*

So in WP Plugin Boilerplate I solved the issue this way:

in the file includes/class-plugin-name.php I have added the follwing code in the define_admin_hooks() function:

```
$this->loader->add_action('plugins_loaded', $plugin_admin, 'check_my_plugin_version');
```

Then in the admin/class-my-plugin-name-admin.php file I have added this simple function:

```
private function check_my_plugin_version()
{
    $options = get_option('my_plugin_options');
    $installed_version = str_replace('.', '', $options['version']);
    // MY_PLUGIN_VERSION is defined in the main plugin file
    $current_version = str_replace('.', '', MY_PLUGIN_VERSION);
    if ($installed_version !== $current_version){
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../includes/class-my-plugin-name-activator.php';
        My_plugin_name_Activator::activate();
    }
}
```

Now the options in the database are updated everytime a new version of the plugin is installed, regardless of how the plugin was updated (automatically, manually using WordPress dashboard or manually using SFTP).